# What can I do when an Android method is depreciated?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I am using the method in kotlin

```
 override fun setUserVisibleHint (isVisibleToUser: Boolean) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint (isVisibleToUser)
    if (isVisibleToUser && isResumed) {
        getTask ()
    }
}
```

but it tells me that it is depreciated, depreciated in java.

this line <strike>setUserVisibleHint</strike>

How can that warning be solved or replaced?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/poYT4.png)

Comment: You hover over the field, or CTRL+click to find the replacement, or you read the docs to find the replacement.

Comment: Do you use that for view pager or?

Comment: It does not give the option to replace, it's just a warning. Yes, I am using a viewpager

Comment: Have a look at the [Android Docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0-alpha07) on this. It recommends you use `setMaxLifecycle()` instead

Answer (score 4):

As per the [Fragment release notes](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment#1.1.0-alpha07):

> - You can now set a max Lifecycle state for a Fragment by calling `setMaxLifecycle()` on a FragmentTransaction. This replaces the now deprecated `setUserVisibleHint()`. `FragmentPagerAdapter` and `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` have a new constructor that allows you to switch to the new behavior. ([b/129780800](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/129780800))

Looking at the `FragmentPagerAdapter` (and the same applies to `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`), you'll note that the default constructor is *also* deprecated, replaced with a second constructor that takes an `int behavior` that can be one of two values:

1. The deprecated [`BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter#BEHAVIOR_SET_USER_VISIBLE_HINT), which is the old behavior where you get a callback to `setUserVisibleHint()` whenever the page changes.
2. The new behavior, [`BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentPagerAdapter#BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT) which only calls `onResume()` on the current Fragment - every other Fragment is only sent `onStart()`.

Therefore if you switch to the new `BEHAVIOR_RESUME_ONLY_CURRENT_FRAGMENT`, then you can move the logic you have in `setUserVisibleHint()` to `onResume()`:

```
override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    getTask()
}
```

If you continue to use the deprecated constructor for your adapter, then you would need to continue to use `setUserVisibleHint()` - you should change both in sync.

Comment: So the lazy fragment initialisation should now be moved to onResume of the fragment instead of setUserVisibleHint where we inflate the viewStub ?

Comment: @rd7773 - yep, you'll only get `onResume()` once you become the current page in the ViewPager.

Comment: Just use `onResume` as replacement for `setUserVisibleHint`. Cool. However, I feel there is 1 or 2 seconds delay for `onResume` to be called, after swiping the page. Is that normal?

Answer (score 0):

So, if you're using view pager, you can do this

```
viewPager?.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

        override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
        }

        override fun onPageScrolled(position: Int, positionOffset: Float, positionOffsetPixels: Int) {

        }
        override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {

        }

    })
```